# How do I authenticate multiple guards in one channel in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, real-time, pusher

I'm building a real time application in Laravel with custom guards using **JWT**: **person-api** for **Person** and **worker-api** for **Worker**. They represent different models, not the same one with roles.

A **Person** may request a certain **Job** and a **Worker** is able to accept that job. I have a dedicated table for each model, **jobs** being the intermediary table between a **Person** and a **Worker**, with a **person_id** and **worker_id**. When a **Job** is requested, the **worker_id** column is set to null until a **Worker** takes it.

When a **Person** requests a **Job** an event is fired and broadcasted in a private channel called Jobs. I'm able to authorize the person in that channel by checking the **person_id** of the job in the event. At this moment, the job is available to any **Worker** until one takes it, and then only the **Worker** who took it is able to perform actions on that **Job**.

My question is, how do I achieve multiple authentication with two different guards in one same channel where the authorization method may vary depending on the state of the **Job**?

For example:

- When a **Job** is requested, I can authorize the **Person** with the person_id of the job, but the worker_id is null, so it's open to any **Worker**
- When a **Worker** takes the job, the authorization for the **Person** stays the same, but now only the **Worker** who took it is authorized in the channel
- When a **Worker** drops the job, it becomes available again to any **Worker**

This is the code in my channels routes for broadcasting:

```
Broadcast::channel('job.{job}', function ($user, \App\Job $job) {
    // authorization condition goes here
});
```

Where `$user` might be a **Person** or a **Worker**, and the authorization condition might change depending on the event of the job in the same channel.

EDIT: My question was marked as a possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614259/jwt-authentication-refresh-token-implementation) and I disagree. I'm not just talking about authenticating users with JWT, that's implemented already. I'm talking about authenticating multiple users with different guards in one same broadcast channel and changing the authorization condition according to the type of user and status of the job.

Comment: Could you not just do `if (auth('worker')->check())` and `if (auth('person')->check())`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy where exactly? I know I could write a custom middleware to override the `$user` for the Closure, but still I need to check the authorization depending on the user and "state" of the job.

Comment: You can just do it inside of the `broadcast` and return true whenever you want.

Comment: So far I don think you can do it with predefined Boardcasting::routes(), u can write your own auth route to do that. or don use with multi-auth but role on user will do